# Influx Measurement Java POJO - missing @TimeColumn decorator (but have @Measurement and @Column)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, influxdb

I can use the `@Measurement` and `@Column` decorators, but my IntelliJ/gradle setup can't find the `@TimeColumn` decorator.

If I navigate to the definition of `@Measurement` (which I believe is decompiled by IntelliJ using the jar that gradle pulls in), I can see that the folder (that should mirror [this part of the influx client library](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/tree/master/src/main/java/org/influxdb/annotation)) doesn't have a `TimeColumn.java`.

One thing to note, I did have to force two dependencies in gradle, but here's some snippets from the relevant gradle build file:

```
resolutionStrategy {
    failOnVersionConflict()
    force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'
    force 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        [group: 'org.influxdb', name: 'influxdb-java', version: "2.15"]
    )
}
```

Here's the inner class I was creating to write an Influx unit test:

```
@Measurement(name = "TestMeasurement")
class TestMeasurement {
    @TimeColumn
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Instant time;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private int value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@TimeColumn` annotation has been added in influxdb-java 2.16, see https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

it's so strange. this link is java class of this library you can add this class manual to your project if you want. although I get time manual of query instead of using mapping columns.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/influxdb/annotation/TimeColumn.java

Comment: If you go to the versions section of the git repo, and download a zip, you can see that it's not there. I'm guessing this feature is intended for the next release, and they updated the docs preemptively

Answer (score 0):

`@TimeColumn` is new annotation add in master branch which is not release yet. if you want to test influxdb java client POJO feature you can follow this readme file:https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/tree/influxdb-java-2.15, in this readme file time just have `@Column` annotation. so for your test demo, just remove 
`@TimeColumn`